# How to suspend watchdog counter during debugging with Segger J-link pro and Stm32cubeIDE

Tags: debugging, stm32, watchdog, segger-jlink, stm32cubeide

I'm trying to debug my application with the Segger J-link since the ST-Link debugger that comes with the Nucleo dev board allows only 5 breakpoints.

I cannot find a way to stop the watchdog during debugging sessions. Where can I find such setting?

If I use the ST-link for debugging this option is available in the following window:

[image]

but, when I select J-Link, that option is not there anymore:

[image]

I found something on SO about adding specific instructions ([Disabling the STM32 IWDG during debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32532916/disabling-the-stm32-iwdg-during-debugging)), but I'm looking for something that does not require to add code.

Answer (score -2):

> but I'm looking for something that does not require to add code

The answer is:

1. Easy way: **change the IDE**.
2. The moderate way: **amend the debug startup script** (https://wiki.segger.com/J-Link_script_files)
3. The hard way: **rewrite the debug plugin**